# Confused about the definition of node.js

Tags: node.js, server, runtime

I am new to web development and networks, I was wondering if someone can help me clear some definitions up.

According to a definition given by my professor: "Node.js is a runtime which provides custom tools and libraries for a specific environment. It is basically JavaScript running on the server".

What is the environment exactly? Is it the webserver? But aren't we building a server from the start using node.js?

Also, by saying running on the server, does he mean: 'running on the machine you are using'? Like, being able to run javascript without using the browser?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a just-in-time compiled language meaning that it requires a runtime environment for the code to be compiled and executed. All modern browsers have V8 compiler build in them by default, node.js is just a v8 runtime environment without the browser. So basically node.js (or deno.js) is just how you execute JavaScript code without the browser

Comment: "All modern browsers have V8 compiler build in them by default"
Not **all**, Firefox has [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey) and Safari [doesn't use V8 either](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit#JavaScriptCore).

Comment: fair enough.. correct way would be that almost all modern browsers have a default javascript engine in them, be that v8 or other interpreters

Answer (score 0):

Let's not make it so complicated, in context of software engineering a runtime environment is simply an environment that a piece of software needs to run.

For example you might have Googled **PC Requirements for GTA-V** and you found the following answer:

Minimum System Requirements:

- **OS**: Windows 8.1 64 Bit, Windows 8 64 Bit, Windows 7 64 Bit Service Pack 1
- **Processor**: Intel Core 2 Quad CPU Q6600 @ 2.40GHz (4 CPUs) / AMD Phenom 9850 Quad-Core Processor (4 CPUs) @ 2.5GHz
- **Memory**: 4GB
- **Video Card**: NVIDIA 9800 GT 1GB / AMD HD 4870 1GB (DX 10, 10.1, 11)
- **Sound Card**: 100% DirectX 10 compatible
- **HDD Space**: 65GB

What are these? These are the <strike>environment variables</strike> which you <strike>need to run GTA-V</strike>, another way to say the same thing is:

This is `runtime environment` for GTA-V.

So when you say Node.js is JavaScript runtime environment you simply mean that Node.js provides `everything` (from software perspective) to run JavaScriptic code on the hardware (Mobiles, Laptops, etc). That `everything` includes interfaces to the Operating Systems of that particular hardwares.

> **Note:** Both of the below statements are correct:

- Node.js is JavaScript runtime environment (RTE).
- Node.js and OS on which Node.js is installed makes Runtime Environment for JavaScript.

##### Technical side

Runtime environment, primarily implements portions of an execution model.

The `execution model` specifies the `behavior` of elements of the language. By applying the execution model, one can derive the behavior of a program that was written in terms of that programming language.

Ok I know that `console.log("Hi")` shows me `hi` on the `console`, but how this `behaviour` of that particular string (console.log) is achieved?
Some or all the `underlying steps` which were taken `between` the execution of code and logging of the output constitue `runtime environment`.

Answer (score -1):

Node.js is a JavaScript runtime environment.
The Node.js run-time environment includes everything you need to execute a program written in JavaScript.
Node.js came into existence when the original developers of JavaScript extended it from something you could only run in the browser to something you could run on your machine as a standalone application.

Now you can do much more with JavaScript than just making websites interactive.

JavaScript now has the capability to do things that other scripting languages like Python can do.

Both your browser JavaScript and Node.js run on the V8 JavaScript runtime engine. This engine takes your JavaScript code and converts it into a faster machine code. Machine code is low-level code which the computer can run without needing to first interpret it.

src="https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-exactly-is-node-js-ae36e97449f5/"

Comment: Not every browser run's with the V8 engine! That's wrong.